# Match and use operator on elements in dataframe and subset of dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

say that I have

```r
df1$name <- c('A','B','C','D','E')
df1$val <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

and

```r
df2$name <- c('A','B')
df2$val <-c(6,7)
```

I want to calculate `df2 - df1` s.t. `df3` will be

```r
df3$name <- df2$name
df3$val <- df2$val-df1$val[df1$name==df2$name]
```

and "match" the names so that

```r
df3$val<-c(6-1,7-2)
```

would be the output. I tried doing this but I couldn't get the syntax correct, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[df1, val := val - i.val, on = .(name)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = LETTERS[1:5], val = 1:5)
df2 <- data.frame(name = LETTERS[1:2], val = 6:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R:

```r
### your starting data
df1 <- data.frame(name=c('A','B','C','D','E'), val=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
df2 <- data.frame(name=c('A','B'), val=c('6','7'))

### fix strings-to-integers
df2$val <- as.integer(df2$val) # since we want to subtract

### merge and subtract
out <- merge(df1, df2, by = "name")
out$val <- out$val.y - out$val.x
out
#   name val.x val.y val
# 1    A     1     6   5
# 2    B     2     7   5
```

And as akrun started with, this is a merge/join operation; for good discussion and examples on that, see [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272), https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188334/3358272.